# Variable reuse and efficiency

Tags: c#, performance, variables

I'm parsing through a text file and a lot of what I'm doing involves code like:

```
int jobTypeStart = contents.IndexOf("JobType: ");
int jobTypeEnd = contents.IndexOf("\r\n", jobtypeStart);
string jobType = contents.Substring(jobtypeStart, 
    (jobTypeEnd - jobTypeStart )).Replace("JobType: ","");
```

This same basic pattern is repeated 30 different times per file and hundreds or thousands of files are in a foreach loop. Is it more efficient to declare a new variable each time, or to reuse those int variables and just change the IndexOf that I'm looking for? So for the sake of clarity, should my next block of code be:

```
int userNameStart = contents.IndexOf("UserName: ");
int userNameEnd = contents.IndexOf("\r\n", userNameStart);
string userName= contents.Substring(userNameStart, 
    (userNameEnd - userNameStart)).Replace("UserName: ","");
```

Or should the whole thing be more like:

```
int stringStart = contents.IndexOf("JobType: ");
int stringEnd = contents.IndexOf("\r\n", stringStart);
string jobType = contents.Substring(stringStart , 
    (stringEnd  - stringStart)).Replace("JobType: ","");

stringStart = contents.IndexOf("UserName: ");
stringEnd = contents.IndexOf("\r\n", stringStart);
string userName= contents.Substring(stringStart , 
    (stringEnd  - stringStart)).Replace("UserName: ","");
```

Or am I overcomplicating something that really doesn't matter that much?

Cheers.

Comment: This really doesn't matter...

Comment: Have you got a performance bottleneck that is a real problem and you can measure and you have narrowed down to this bit of code? If not, you should DEFINITELY DO NOTHING. "Premature optimisation is the root of all evil" as the cliched quote goes.

Comment: @Russell - no bottleneck, I was typing out the code and wondered what the SO hivemind would think. The suggestion below of refactoring into a method is a better answer anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should refactor this into a method:

```
private string Extract(string text, string field)
{
    int stringStart = text.IndexOf(field);
    int stringEnd = text.IndexOf("\r\n", stringStart);
    return text.Substring(stringStart , (stringEnd  - stringStart)).Replace(field,"");
}
```

and call it like

```
string userName = Extract(contents, "UserName :");
```

I'd favor readability in this case.

Comment: Almost.. change `text` to `contents` and it actually compiles ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your initial way is fine. int and string are value types in your declaration, that get pulled out of the heap each time you go for another loop iteration, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I can see a pattern. Why don't you put all your variables (JobType, UserName...) into a list and iterate over them for the string.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a method that does this stuff will help out?

```
 private string DoStuff(string contents, string matchString)
 {
     int stringStart = contents.IndexOf(matchString + ": ");
     int stringEnd = contents.IndexOf("\r\n", stringStart);
     return contents.Substring(stringStart, (stringEnd - stringStart)).Replace(matchString + ": ", "");
 }
```

And then call it everytime:

```
string jobType = DoStuff(contents, "JobType");
string userName = DoStuff(contents, "UserName");
```